# Using entities from another file in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

How does one "include" another file from a workspace in VHDL and then use an architecure of an entity that is implemented in another file? Here is what I have but it is not right:

**updated code:**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library Part2;
use Part2.all;


entity problem4Gates is
    port(X,Clk: in std_logic; Q: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) ;
end entity problem4Gates;  

architecture behavioral OF problem4Gates IS  

for all: yourGateName use entity  Part2.JKflipFlop(jkFF); --port (J, K, Clk, Preset, Clear : in std_logic; Q, Qn : Buffer std_logic) --JKflipFlop --jkFF    
signal s0, ns0, s1, ns1, s2, na2, ps0, ps1, ps2, restart : std_logic :='0';
begin
    process(clk)
    begin                  
         yourgatename( ns0, clk, '0', restart, Q(0), ns0 );
    end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

I now get 2 errors:

```
# Error: COMP96_0078: Part3.vhd : (13, 10): Unknown identifier "yourGateName".
# Error: COMP96_0134: Part3.vhd : (13, 10): Cannot find component declaration.
```

Comment: Show the entity declaration for DflipFlop, it's Interface list, use named association, show us any warnings or error messages. Depending on the tools if it is not included in the current project it isn't in the current working library, your tools would have a way of naming the library for a different project. It has to have been analyzed prior to elaboration of problem4Gates. There's also configured and component instantiation besides direct entity instantiation. If the flipflop is in Library Part2, replace work.Dflipflop(dFF) with Part2.DflipFlop(dFF). You're not providing enough information.

Comment: the entity instantiation looks possibly OK EXCEPT that it shouldn't be in a process! Put it in the architecture section  - outside the process.

Comment: I talked to my teacher and he said this:
ibrary yourDesignLibrary;
use yourDesignLibrary.all;



Next, for each gate, include in the same area as your signal assignments the following statement


`for all: yourGateName use entity yourDesignLibrary.yourGateEntity(yourGateDesign); --use yourGateName where ever you need it`

I am getting 2 errors on compilation, I edited my post with the new code

Comment: @BrianDrummond has a very valid point, A component instantiation is a concurrent statement, which can't appear as a process statement part. Your history shows it was always there (and I didn't notice). Move it to the architecture statement part of the architecture body. You need a component declaration for the YourGateName component instantiation. "The component name, if present, must be the name of a component declared in a component declaration."

Comment: There isn't enough detail about your assignment but the apparent instantiation of a flip flop in the process statement doesn't appear to be sufficient by itself.  The port interface list for problem4gates doesn't match, nor does the number of signals you declared in the architecture declarative part. Other than the hints provided here, when you get it working answer your own question. Depending on reputation, after 12 hours or so you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

> How does one "include" another file from a workspace in VHDL and then use an architecure of an entity that is implemented in another file?

You don't "include a file".  VHDL is not C.

If you compile several different architectures of a particular entity they can all be in one file, even the same file as the entity, or they can be scattered across multiple files.

You can then make use of them - the easiest way is direct instantiation.  In the higher-level architecture, you do:

```
inst_of_one_arch     : entity work.some_entity(one_arch) port map....
inst_of_another_arch : entity work.some_entity(another_arch) port map....
```

There are other ways, but they can be a lot of hassle.

Comment: Say I wanted to use two of these entities with signals in my current file. Would I need to make a new instance every time I wanted to use that entity?

Comment: When you say "I want to use two of these entities" I think you mean to say "I want to use two instances of an entity", so yes.  I don't know if you have a software background, but often this sort of confusion comes from those who do... you wouldn't say "I want to use two of these functions" you would say "I want to call this function twice".