# Put attributes into file possible?

Tags: attributes, vhdl

I am having a huge list of attributes being comprised of KEEP, 
DONT_TOUCH and MARK_DEBUG. It's mainly the list of signals I want to 
debug within my design. Since the list takes up so much space I was 
wondering if it's possible to somehow store all those attributes within 
a file and load them into my VHDL-design depending on a global 
constant-variable/signal/whatever?

So it would look something like this:

```
entity top is
end top ;
architecture Behavioral of top is
    if(DEBUG_ENABLE = "TRUE") then
        include "../path/to/file.txt";
    end if;
begin
end Behavioral;
```

and the file would look something like this:

```
attribute KEEP          : string;
attribute DONT_TOUCH    : string;
attribute MARK_DEBUG    : string;

attribute KEEP of signal_1            : signal is "TRUE";
attribute KEEP of signal_2            : signal is "TRUE";

attribute DONT_TOUCH of signal_1      : signal is "TRUE";
attribute DONT_TOUCH of signal_2      : signal is "TRUE";

attribute MARK_DEBUG of signal_1      : signal is "TRUE";
attribute MARK_DEBUG of signal_2      : signal is "TRUE";
```

Anyone knows, whether that is possible?

Cheers

EDIT:
I don't mean to include libraries via use-statement. This is mainly for including other components or type/array/function/procedure-declarations into your entity. I want to include something into the architecture head which is not a component or similar which in the first place has no reference to my entity design, unless I explicitly instantiate it. I want to include something that describes the declared signals within my architecture head. As far as my understanding goes, this is not possible with libraries and packages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to to create include files in vhdl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414682/how-to-to-create-include-files-in-vhdl).   Note attributes have to be associated (specified) with entities of various classes within the scope of their declarations.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement conditional attributes like this:

```
attribute KEEP : BOOLEAN;

constant ENABLE_DEBUG : BOOLEAN := TRUE;
attribute KEEP of mySignal : signal is ENABLE_DEBUG;
```

Conditional string assignments can be solved by a ite (if-then-else) function.

```
function ite(cond : BOOLEAN; val1 : STRING ; val2 : STRING) return STRING is
begin
  if cond then
    return val1;
  else
    return val2;
  end if;
end function;

attribute FSM_ENCODING : STRING;
attribute FSM_ENCODING of State : signal is ite(ENABLE_DEBUG, "gray", "auto");
```

Some attributes can be loaded/assigned via vendor dependent constraint files.

**Xilinx ISE example:**
For example KEEP can be assigned in Schematic, VHDL and Verilog or via Xilinx XCF, NCF or UCF files.
See [Xilinx Constraint Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/cgd.pdf) for details on what attributes can be assigned where (Page 21) to which tool (synth. map, P&R, ...).

```
NET "myInstance/mySignal" KEEP;
```

**Xilinx Vivado example:**
Vivado supports the 'DONT_TOUCH' attribute, which can be set via XDC files. See Vivado's [Using Constraints](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_1/ug903-vivado-using-constraints.pdf) user guide for more details. The following example is from page 56:

```
set_property DONT_TOUCH true [get_cells fsm_reg]
```

So have a look into your synthesis tool's user guide and the list of supported attributes/constraints.

Comment: If I declare attributes within the XDC-files don't I need the actual netlist name of that signal after synth, do I? As far as my understanding goes, I would need the name after synth which can become pretty messy. Because of that I would like to include the attributes within my VHDL-files, so I can keep the pretty names of my signals (i.e. signal_1) and not the crypto ones, meaning: signal_1_[reg][0:0]

Comment: @SteffenKern, yes you do, but Xilinx should keep your names as much as possible. It may be better too, since you debug the design the way it will be implemented, `keep` and al will alter the ouput of the synthesis. Otherwise, using external files it becomes easy to exclude those constraints, and they support regexp. Vivado even support, through TCL, easy targeting of all flip-flop of an entity, for instance, in a convenient TCL command. If a signal you need has disapear, you can always add the attribute in VHDL.

Comment: I hope we are not talking at cross-purposes here, but excactly that is what I would like to accomplish. I.e. when I add the line "attribute KEEP of data_a : signal is "TRUE";" into my architecture (+a mark_debug on the same signal) and the signal AFTER synth is called data_a_[0], well... one can clearly see that its the same signal before and after synth and the mark_debug stays on that signal. I just thought that there is maybe a construct to "outsource" all those keeps and mark_debugs into a seperate file(not XDC!) and make it optional to include it. Just for the purpose of clean code style.

Comment: You can use a separate XDC that you conditionally include in your build script (if you are doing batch compilation). That's one of the reasons constraint files exist, I doubt you'll find a different mechanism to do the same thing. You can have pre-synth XDCs that don't need to call out the garbled names.
@JonathanDrolet in my experience ISE does do a good job of keeping your names as much as possible. Not so much with Vivado.