# VHDL version of 'include

Tags: vhdl

This is similar to [How to to create include files in vhdl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414682/how-to-to-create-include-files-in-vhdl), but I am not satisfied with the answer.

In verilog, I can declare wires/registers and create a .vh file. Then, I can 'include my.vh file. This is very useful because I can use python scripts (or whatever) to auto generate tedious wire/reg assignments.

My question is, does something like this exist for VHDL? I am using a python script to generated a synthesized RAM module (each signal with its own address, some registers being sign extended, some be ro, etc). It would be really nice and clean if I could have something like a 'include .... and bring in all of these registers and signal names to my top module.

Thank you

Comment: I guess you looking for something called a verilog pre-processor (VPP).

Comment: Use a package in VHDL like the other answer says.

Comment: VHDL has no pre-processor, so there is no equivalent of ` `include `

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Auto-generating VHDL packages and other files in Python is a well trodden path.